# Table \rowcolor \columncolor \multirow and \multicolumn Alignment

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I'm trying to recreate this table from Word in LaTeX:

[image]

I'm getting close, but the "Effectiveness" section is not aligned properly, and the "Probability" section is not fully filled in with color.

[image]

Here is the code I have so far, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{3cm}{\centering \cellcolor{gray!50} Effectiveness of Controls} &    \multicolumn{3}{p{9cm}|}{\centering \cellcolor{gray!50} Probability of Threat Occurrence (Natural or Environmental Threats) or Threat Motivation and Capability (Human Threats)} \\
\cline{2-4}
\rowcolor{gray!50}
& Low & Moderate & High \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white!50}
\cellcolor{gray!50} Low & Moderate & High & High \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white!50}
\cellcolor{gray!50} Moderate & Low & Moderate & High \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white!50}
\cellcolor{gray!50} High & Low & Low & Moderate \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Risk Classifications}
\label{tab:xyz}

\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want `\multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 9cm+2\arrayrulewidth+4\tabcolsep\relax}|}{`  to span over the rules and cell padding as well as the 3 cells, although I needed to reduce the `3cm` and `9cm` to make the table fit on a page.

Comment: Ah, that looks much better. The command is a bit convoluted, I don't expect I would have sorted that out on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can align `Effectiveness...` by

```
\multirow{2}{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}[-0.5cm]{...
```

Note `[-0.5cm]` and adjust it for vertical positioning. I have adjusted the column width such that they fit well within the text width.

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|C{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
           |C{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
           |C{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}[-0.5cm]{\centering \cellcolor{gray!50} Effectiveness of Controls} &    \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.75\textwidth-\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\centering Probability of Threat Occurrence (Natural or Environmental Threats) or Threat Motivation and Capability (Human Threats)} \\
\cline{2-4}
\cellcolor{gray!50}
& \cellcolor{gray!50} Low & \cellcolor{gray!50} Moderate & \cellcolor{gray!50} High \\
\hline
%\rowcolor{white!50}
\cellcolor{gray!50} Low & Moderate & High & High \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white!50}
\cellcolor{gray!50} Moderate & Low & Moderate & High \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white!50}
\cellcolor{gray!50} High & Low & Low & Moderate \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Risk Classifications}
\label{tab:xyz}

\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This type of tabulars are very easy to build in [cals](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cals). As you will see, no white lines in the gray, all rules equally visible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals, caption, xcolor}

\let\nc=\nullcell           % CALS Shortcuts for spanning cells
\let\sc=\spancontent


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{calstable}[c]  % Centred CALS tabular

% Calculate the column width
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/4\relax}
    }

% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 4

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside horizontal frame rules
\def\cals@framecs@width{0,4pt}   % Outside vertical frame rules
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}    % Rule between header and tabular body
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}        % Inside vertical rules
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}        % Inside horizontal rules
\def\cals@bgcolor{}              % To avoid undefined

\def\gray{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{gray!30}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

% R1H1     % Just a comment: Row one, header row one
\thead{
\brow
    \gray\alignC\nc{lrt}    % Switch to gray background and centred text, works until switched off
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\vfil Probability of Threat Occurrence (Natural or Environmental Threats) or Threat Motivation and Capability (Human Threats)}
\erow
%R2H2       % Row two, header row two
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil Effectiveness of Controls}  % "vfil" centres the cell content vertically
    \cell{\vfil Low}
    \cell{\vfil Moderate}
    \cell{\vfil High}\gray % Always reset colour at end of header 
\erow
}  % closing 'thead' clause
%R3B1     % Row three, body row one
\brow
    \gray\cell{Low}\gray   % Switch to gray background for first cell (column 1)
    \cell{\vfil Moderate}
    \cell{\vfil High}
    \cell{\vfil High}
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \gray\cell{Moderate}\gray
    \cell{\vfil Low}
    \cell{\vfil Moderate}
    \cell{\vfil High}
\erow
%R5B3
\brow
    \gray\cell{High}\gray
    \cell{\vfil Low}
    \cell{\vfil Low}
    \cell{\vfil Moderate}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\caption{Risk Classifications}
\label{tab:xyz}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can draw this tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines,columns-width=3cm] 
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!50}{1,2} 
  \columncolor{gray!50}{1}
\Body
  \Block{2-1}{Effectiveness of\\ Controls} &    
  \Block{1-3}{Probability of Threat Occurrence (Natural or\\
            Environmental Threats) or Threat Motivation and\\
             Capability (Human Threats)} \\
      & Low & Moderate & High \\
  Low & Moderate & High & High \\
  Moderate & Low & Moderate & High \\
  High & Low & Low & Moderate \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Risk Classifications}
\label{tab:xyz}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

- You need several compilations.
- The rules won't seem to disappear at some levels of zoom as you have when using `colortbl` in some PDF viewers (e.g. Adobe Reader).
- You won't have thin white lines (between the cells 1-1 and 1-2) as you have when using `colortbl` in some PDF viewers (e.g. SumatraPDF or PDF.js used in Firefox).

[image: Ouput of the above code]