# Table: white spacing with rowcolor, multicolumn and multirow

Tags: tables, spacing, multirow, multicolumn, rowcolor

I have the following table :

[image: problematic table]

It uses `\rowcolor`, `\multicolumn`, `\multirow` but it also has a wide white spacing between the cases.

I need the title "Cobertura del transporte en el municipio de Monterrey" to be properly centered, respecting the 2 cases width, the padding and the space between the left, right and the cases below it.

I also need to combine the two green cases rounded by the red ellipse and containing the "91.4%" value. These two cases would then become one (cf. the `\multirow` attempt below) green case spanning between the two rows and respecting the height and padding.

I've been trying to get my table right with [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168248/table-rowcolor-columncolor-multirow-and-multicolumn-alignment), only it does not seem to apply to my particular example because of the white spacing.

The code for this table is the following :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

%------Column types--------------
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%------Space between cases-------
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 2pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\newcolumntype{+}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 2pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}
\makeatother

%-------Colors--------------------
\definecolor{table1}{RGB}{255,129,54}
\definecolor{table2}{RGB}{41,148,178}
\definecolor{table3}{RGB}{255,129,54}
\definecolor{table4}{RGB}{220,220,77}
\definecolor{table5}{RGB}{58,58,58}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\color{white}\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{L{3cm}+C{3cm}+C{3cm}+C{3cm}}

    \rowcolor{table5}
    Otra cosa & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Cobertura del transporte en el municipio de Monterrey} & Otra cosa\\

    \thickhline
    \rowcolor{table4}
    - & \cellcolor{table3}\textcolor{table5}{Primer Cuadro} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{table5}{91.4\%}} & -\\

    \thickhline
    \rowcolor{table4}
    - & \cellcolor{table3}\textcolor{table5}{Centro (Poniente)} &  & -\\

    \thickhline
    \rowcolor{table4}
    - & \cellcolor{table3}\textcolor{table5}{Oeste} & \textcolor{table5}{90.1\%} & -\\
    \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note : I obviously tried replacing the line

`\multicolumn{2}{c}{Cobertura del transporte en el municipio de Monterrey}`

by this one :

`\multicolumn{2}{C{6cm}}{Cobertura del transporte en el municipio de Monterrey}`

but it did not provide anything good :

[image]

Does anyone has a proper solution for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simplified your code: thick \hlines are already defined by the `makecell` package. It also defines thick \clines, unfortunately it didn't work in this context, for some reason, so I had to use a workaround with `\hhline`. The second title is an argument to the `\makecell` command, that allows for line breaks inside cells.

The trick to make appear the multirow contents is to write it in the `second` row, with a negative value (-2) for the number of rows. I used the `\multirowcell` from the makecell package since it has a slighly simpler syntax than `\multirow`.

I took the liberty to have column heads in boldface, as I think white characters on  a coloured background are not very readable. This is obtained very simply using the `\thead` command and setting `\theadfont` to `\bfseries` in the preamble. In addition I set the first column qualifier to `C` instead of `L` as I don't why it should be different from the last column (but of course you may have reasons to stick to L for the real table).

Finally I removed unnecessary packages for the table.

Here is the code:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%------Column types--------------
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%------Space between cases-------
\newcommand\thickhline{\Xhline{2pt}}
%-------Colors--------------------
\definecolor{table1}{RGB}{255,129,54}
\definecolor{table2}{RGB}{41,148,178}
\definecolor{table3}{RGB}{255,129,54}
\definecolor{table4}{RGB}{220,220,77}
\definecolor{table5}{RGB}{58,58,58}

\newcommand*\thickvrule[1][2pt]{\vrule width 2pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{m}
\usepackage{hhline}
\setlength\doublerulesep{1.2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\color{white}\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{C{3cm}!{\thickvrule} S{C{3cm}}!{\thickvrule}C{3cm}!{\thickvrule}C{3cm}}
    \rowcolor{table5}
    \thead{Otra cosa} & \multicolumn{2}{Sc!{\thickvrule}}{ \thead{Cobertura del transporte en\\el municipio de Monterrey}} & \thead{Otra cosa} \\
    \thickhline
  \rowcolor{table4}
    -- & \cellcolor{table3}\textcolor{table5}{Primer Cuadro} && -- \\
 \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{white}}=|=|~|=}
    \rowcolor{table4}
    -- & \cellcolor{table3}\textcolor{table5}{Centro (Poniente)} & \multirowcell{-2}{\makebox[3cm]{\textcolor{table5}{91.4\%}}} & -- \\
    \thickhline
    \rowcolor{table4}
   -- & \cellcolor{table3}\textcolor{table5}{Oeste} & \textcolor{table5}{90.1\%} & -- \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your code is very nice. There's only one little issue : the white spacing is not respected for the `\multicolumn` case "Cobertura del transporte en el municipio de Monterrey"...

Comment: You managed to get combine the two cells -- impressive. For the spacing issue, just look on my solution -- you may grab it;-) It's ok if the OP accepts your answer

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Yes, it's a good solution that would spare me loading `makecell`. However makecell also lets me have a common formatting for column heads (e.g. boldface, which would look better for black background) and easily define thick hlines.

Comment: @jrojasqu: I'm not sure I understand well: you want to keep the white column under `Monterrey` that we see in your first figure?

Comment: @Bernard Well, sorry the delay... In fact I was talking about the white spacing at the right and left of the "Cobertura...Monterrey" case. But then I now see that your code is flawless! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The OP forgot the `\tabcolsep` width to the left and the right of in the relevant `\multicolumn` command. It can be reduced to `0pt` using the `@{}` statement. The inner two `\tabcolsep` widths must be added to the width of 6cm.

```
\multicolumn{2}{@{}C{6cm+2\tabcolsep+2pt}@{}}{Cobertura del transporte en el municipio de Monterrey}
```

However, there is an additional `\vrule` command, having a with of `2pt`, this must be added to.

I would suggest to introduce a `\newlength{\myvrulewidth}` having the value `2pt`, to simplify the maintenance of the code.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

%------Column types--------------
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%------Space between cases-------
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 2pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\newcolumntype{+}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 2pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}
\makeatother

%-------Colors--------------------
\definecolor{table1}{RGB}{255,129,54}
\definecolor{table2}{RGB}{41,148,178}
\definecolor{table3}{RGB}{255,129,54}
\definecolor{table4}{RGB}{220,220,77}
\definecolor{table5}{RGB}{58,58,58}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\color{white}\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{L{3cm}+C{3cm}+C{3cm}+C{3cm}}

    \rowcolor{table5}
    Otra cosa & \multicolumn{2}{@{}C{6cm+2\tabcolsep+2pt}@{}}{Cobertura del transporte en el municipio de Monterrey} & Otra cosa\\

    \thickhline
    \rowcolor{table4}
    - & \cellcolor{table3}\textcolor{table5}{Primer Cuadro} & \multirow{-1}{*}{\textcolor{table5}{91.4\%}} & -\\

    \thickhline
    \rowcolor{table4}
    - & \cellcolor{table3}\textcolor{table5}{Centro (Poniente)} &  & -\\

    \thickhline
    \rowcolor{table4}
    - & \cellcolor{table3}\textcolor{table5}{Oeste} & \textcolor{table5}{90.1\%} & -\\
    \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The question/solution is somehow connected to [Unwanted padding in tabular columns when cells contain multiple rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195899/unwanted-padding-in-tabular-columns-when-cells-contain-multiple-rows/195902#195902)

**Edit** Thanks to the comment by Harish Kumar, the shifted line in the 3rd row could be corrected

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar: I was working on the main issue first ... but thanks -- however, it should rather read `-1`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Yes, but what's the use of having `91.4%` hanging between two table rows (as would be the consequence of using `-2`? It's dubious ;-)

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thanks ;-) By the way: Congrats to your > 100k rep ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks! But how do I get the "91.4%" value properly centered (by combining/mixing the two green cases into one) vertically? I may be missing the something in your answer, only I just don't get it...

Comment: @jrojasqu: That's something I do not understand correctly. You want to shift down the `91.4%` down, and the two green cases in the 3rd column, 2nd and 3rd. row being combined?

Comment: @jrojasqu: Perhaps you should use an image of your table, draw a circle around the cells you want to have combined... that's much clearer. I am confused by `two cases containing the ... value` -- the value is in one green case...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I edited the question again, taking your comments into account.

Comment: @jrojasqu: Oh my, I feared you would mean that ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :( Sorry... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that table easily with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 5.18 of 2021-07-15).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\sffamily
\begin{NiceTabular}
   [
     rules={color=white,width=2pt},
     hvlines-except-borders,
     columns-width=3cm,
     cell-space-limits=5pt
   ]
   {cccc}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[RGB]{220,220,77}{2-4}
  \columncolor[RGB]{255,129,54}{2}
  \rowcolor[RGB]{58,58,58}{1}
\Body
\RowStyle{\bfseries\color{white}}
Otra cosa & \Block[C]{1-2}{Cobertura del transporte en\\el municipio de Monterrey} &&Otra cosa \\ 
-- & Primer Cuadro     & \Block{2-1}{91.4\%} & -- \\ 
-- & Centro (Poniente) &                     & -- \\ 
-- & Oeste             & 90.1\%              & -- \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]