# Compatibility of bigdelim and rowcolors

Tags: tables, color, bigdelim

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{green!25}{green!75}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \ldelim\{{3}{*}& 1 & 2 & 3 \\
                   & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
                   & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

As you can see the row coloring covers the bigdelim which I think should not happen.

Is there a possibility to see the bigdelim when using rowcolors?

Related questions

- [Table: white spacing with rowcolor, multicolumn and multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200075/8917)

**Update**

The very helpful answer from Zarko unfortunately does not work when removing the intercolumn space with

```
\begin{tabular}{c@{}ccc}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{green!25}{green!75}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
                 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
                 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\ldelim\{{-3}{*} & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

:-)

[image]

As you see, you need first to write table with color and on the end add (in last table row) big delimiter (which had to span rows before it, hence `-` at number of rows!

**Addendum:**
While you are waiting for bug fix for `bigdelim` package, maybe you may use the following solution with use of the `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy}
\tikzset{
B/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
            raise=1pt, mirror},% for mirroring of brace
            thick,
            pen colour=black},
F/.style args = {#1/#2}{fill=#1, blend mode = multiply, 
                        inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2, fit=#2}
        }

\begin{document}
    \[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}      
\begin{NiceArray}{R@{}CCC}%
[create-large-nodes,
 code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}[name suffix=-large]
                    \draw[B] (1-2.north west) -- (3-2.south west);
                    \node [F=green!25/(2-1) (2-4)] {} ;
                    \node [F=green!75/(3-1) (3-4)] {} ;
                    \end{tikzpicture}}
    ]
~~ & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
~~ & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
~~ & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{NiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}
```

For correct result you need to compile above MWE at least twice.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is an easy solution. Thanks.

Comment: Great suggestion....

Comment: Follow up question: it does not work anymore when I want to squeeze the intercolumn space with `\begin{tabular}{c@{}ccc}`. Do you happen to know what to do then?

Comment: Unfortunately,  `\bigdelim` doesn't work ' with `colortbl` (or `[table]{xcolor}`) well. This seems to be a bug (or missed features). Try to report it or contact package authors.

Comment: @Hotschke, my answer solve your original question ... It is not my fault, if packages has bugs and not help you at your follow-up question in comment. It will be fer from you, that about this you ask new question, that some other can help you and this question consider as solved.

Comment: @Zarko It was not meant to be offensive when removing the check mark. I just wanted to indicate to others that alternative answers are still worth posting. I hope you can agree on this. I already contacted the current maintainer of multirow/bigdelim. He is currently on holiday and wants to look into this issue next week. And obviously this is not your fault. I think no one has thought so. I suspect you down-voted my question which I cannot understand. Anyhow, I still appreciate and be thankful for your answer but still hope to get further answers as well.

Comment: @Hotschke, I disagree with you. Than you should not accept answer in the first place.

Comment: Why do you disagree? I was not aware that the standard intercolumn specification `@{}` is important for this question. If I would have known this in the first place, I would have added it to the initial example. I consider questions not carved in stone after I pressed submit. I am allowed to edit for clarification.  Asking the question with the most suitable MWE in the first place is difficult. Also IMHO asking every small variation of a question separately, adds more clutter to the whole site. I am happy if do not have to search too long for an answer without checking all related questions.

Comment: @Hotschke, new demand, new question. And I will not argue with you.

Comment: I finally found out this is a problem with the `colortbl` package, as it extends its color into the first column (it assumes that there is the normal intercolumn space, which it fills with the color to prevent gaps between the columns. It can be solved by using `\begin{tabular}{c@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}ccc}`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out this is a problem with the colortbl package, as it extends its color into the first column (it assumes that there is the normal intercolumn space, which it fills with the color to prevent gaps between the columns. This is called the overhang. It can be changed with `\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]`.
So this gives the solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{green!25}{green!75}

\begin{tabular}{c@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}ccc}
                 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
                 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\ldelim\{{-3}{*} & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{green!25}{green!75}
\Body
& 1 & 2 & 3 \\
& 4 & 5 & 6 \\
& 7 & 8 & 9 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix{\lbrace}{1-2}{3-2}{.}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]