# \rowcolor covers text in tables because of using @{\,} between columns

Tags: tables, multirow, rowcolor

The table contains components of a recipe and i would like to mark replaced components with gray color.

[image: In the colored row a part of the closing bracket and a part of the 1 in the quantity column is covered]

The reason for the coverage seems to be the manual reduction of the space between the columns by `@{\,}`. Without the use of `@{\,}` i do not have the problem with the coverage.
I am looking for a way to prevent the coverage or another way to minimize the space between the number and the unit in the quantity column.
This is my first try of a table with siunitx. Any recomendations are welcome, because the code for the table looks bloated in my eyes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabular}{l@{\,}l
S[table-format=3.2]
r@{\,}s[table-unit-alignment=left]
S[table-format=1.2e1,table-number-alignment=center] }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{Component}} &  {\multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack{{Stock Solution} \\ (\si{\gram\per\liter}\ch{dH2O}) }}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{Quantity}} &
{\multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack{Concentration in \\ Final Medium \\ (\si{\mole\per\liter})}}} \\ % multirow in S-Spalten mit Klammern schützen
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{} &          \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{} &          \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
(1)                                   & NaCl & {---}  & \tablenum[table-format=4.0]{23}                    & g                       & 12.34e-5 \\
\addlinespace
\rowcolor{gray}                       & A1        & 134.56 &                       &                        & 23.56e-7 \\
\rowcolor{gray} \multirow{-2}{*}{(2)} & A2        & 56.78  & {\multirow{-2}{*}{\tablenum[table-format=4.0]{1}}} & {\multirow{-2}{*}{mL}} & 56.47e-4 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{(2)}                  & A2        & 56.78  &  {\multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum[table-format=4.0]{1}}} & {\multirow{2}{*}{mL}}  & 56.47e-4 \\
                                      & A3        & 11.11  &                       &                        & 11.11e-1 \\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: duplicate -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200075/table-white-spacing-with-rowcolor-multicolumn-and-multirow --

Comment: In order to make the code compilable, `\usepackage{chemformula}` is missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table: white spacing with rowcolor, multicolumn and multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200075/table-white-spacing-with-rowcolor-multicolumn-and-multirow)

Comment: @TobiBS: I don't think the suggested duplicate really solves OP's problem. As far as I can see, the problem here is the use of `@{\,}` which does not seem to be the case in the linked question.

Comment: @js bibra In case you suggest the negative row number in `\multirow`, i already use it.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you. added it.

Comment: @Solstafir: Probably you can make use of `NiceTabular` from the `nicematrix` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

Remark that you don't need `\multirow` for the headers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit = 2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{NiceTabular}{L@{\,}LS[table-format=3.2]R@{\,}L%
S[table-format=1.2e1,table-number-alignment=center]}%
[code-before = \rowcolor{lightgray}{3,4}]
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{C}{Component}
& 
{\makecell{{Stock Solution}\\ (\si{\gram\per\liter}\ch{dH2O)}} }
& 
\multicolumn{2}{C}{Quantity}
& 
{\makecell{Concentration in \\ Final Medium \\ (\si{\mole\per\liter})}}
\\ 
\midrule
\addlinespace
(1) & NaCl & {---} & \tablenum[table-format=4.0]{23} & g & 12.34e-5 \\[1mm]
\multirow{2}{*}{(2)} & A1 & 134.56 & {\multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum[table-format=4.0]{1}}} & {\multirow{2}{*}{mL}} & 23.56e-7 \\
& A2 & 56.78  &  &  & 56.47e-4 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{(2)} & A2 & 56.78  & {\multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum[table-format=4.0]{1}}} & {\multirow{2}{*}{mL}}  & 56.47e-4 \\
                 & A3 & 11.11  & & & 11.11e-1 \\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: That looks really good. Even the thin white lines in the colored rows are gone. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Solstafir: Yes. With the coloring tools of `{NiceTabular}`, you won't have the artefacts you see in some PDF viewers at some level of zoom (the rules won't seem to vanish as they do sometimes near colored cells with `colortbl`).

Comment: In this answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `l` instead of  `L` and `r` instead of `R` in the preamble of `{NiceTabular}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

I propose this workaround, replacing `\multirow{3}{...}` with a single coloured row containg in the relevant cells a `\Centerstack` command from `stackengine` and replacing `r@{\,}r` with `r>{\hskip-10pt}s`. Unrelated: I replaced the gray colour with the lighter `Gainsboro` grey to have more readable text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 0.17em}l%
S[table-format=3.2]
r > {\hskip -11pt}s[table-unit-alignment=left]%
S[table-format=1.2e1,table-number-alignment=center] }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Component} & {\Centerstack{Stock Solution \\ (\si{\gram\per\liter} \ch{dH2O})}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Quantity} & {\Centerstack{Concentration in \\ Final Medium \\ (\si{\mole\per\liter})}}
 \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
(1) & NaCl & {---} & \tablenum[table-format=4.0]{23} & g & 12.34e-5 \\
\addlinespace
\rowcolor{Gainsboro} (2)) & \Centerstack{A1 \\ A2}& {\Centerstack[r]{134.56\\ 56.78}} & 1 & mL & {\Centerstack{\num{23.56e-7}\\\num{56.47e-4}}}\\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{(2)} & A2 & 56.78 & {\multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum[table-format=4.0]{1}}} & {\multirow{2}{*}{mL}} & 56.47e-4 \\
                                      & A3 & 11.11 & & & 11.11e-1 \\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this workaround, but i prefer the result with the `nicematrix` package.