# How to put an image on multiple columns in a table ?

Tags: tables, graphics, arrows

So I want to include the following table into my latex document:
[image: Table from Tardieu 2017, Plant Phenomics, From Sensors to Knowledge, Plant Phenomics]

I've reproduced to written part of the table in latex, but I wanted to know if there is a way to recreate the last four rows easily ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `\multicolumn{3}{c}{\includegraphics{some_graphic_file}}` should be enough.

Comment: If you really have a gray background, you may be better off with `tikz`, i.e. building on @Bernard's suggestion: `
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\tikz{\fill[blue] (0,0) -- (3,0.1) -- (3,0.4) -- (0,0.5);}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
% table partly adpated from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168257/121799
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\noindent 
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|C{2cm}
           |C{2.2cm}
           |C{2cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}
sth & sth & sth & sth \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{
\tikz{\draw[fill=blue] (0,0.1) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.3) -- (0,0.2);}}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{
\tikz{\fill[blue] (0,0) -- (4,0.1) -- (4,0.3) -- (0,0.4);}}\\
\hline
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\tikz{\path (2,0.3);
\draw[very thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (4,0)
node[midway,below,font=\sffamily\small]{blah blah blah};
\draw[very thick,-latex] (4,-1) -- (0,-1)
node[midway,below,font=\sffamily\small]{blah blah blah};
}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:xyz}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- one another possibility where:

  - for images is defined basleline for better positioning of images in multi column celss
  - with package `cellspace` vertical space around images is increased
- since you not provide a mwe, in table is used dummy text and set the same width of all columns.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes}
  \usepackage{cellspace}
      \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
      \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
  \begin{document}
      \begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{p{3cm}|}}
      \hline
      \rowcolor{gray!50}
  text    &   text    &   text    &   text    \\
      \hline
      \rowcolor{gray!50}
  text    &   \multicolumn{3}{Sc|}{
          \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]{
          \path[draw=blue,fill=blue!30,thick]
              (0,0.1) -- (6,0.3) -- (6,-0.3) -- (0,-0.1) -- cycle;}
                                  }   \\
      \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!50}
  text    &   \multicolumn{3}{Sc|}{
          \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]{
          \path[draw=blue,fill=blue!30,thick]
              (0,0.3) -- (6,0.1) -- (6,-0.1) -- (0,-0.3) -- cycle;}
                                  }   \\
  \hline
  some longer text in two lines
          &   \multicolumn{3}{Sc|}{
          \tikz[font=\sffamily\small,
                ultra thick, >=Straight Barb,
                auto=right,
                baseline=(current bounding box.base)]{
          \draw[->] (0, 0.0) to ["some longer one line quotes"] +(6,0);
          \draw[<-] (0,-0.8) to ["some longer one line quotes"] +(6,0);}
                                  } \\
          \hline
  \end{tabular}
     \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

  which gives:

[image]